# Selecting multiple cells of special format on website and importing the result back to excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to Excel VBA. I have written some code with the help of online videos but I am stuck to resolve a problem of selecting two cells as Range values separated by commas. However, If I just use one of the selected cells, the compiling error does not occur.

```
Sub elevation_finder()
Dim elevation As Long
Dim ieobject As InternetExplorer
Dim htmlElement As IHTMLElement
Dim i As Integer

i = 1

Set ieobject = New InternetExplorer
ieobject.Visible = True
ieobject.navigate "https://www.freemaptools.com/elevation-finder.htm"

Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")

ieobject.document.getElementById("locationSearchTextBox").Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Header").Range("C2").Value

End Sub
```

My next step after entering the numbers (coordinates as integers) is to import the result back into new column.

Help and suggestion is appreciated to improve the code in automating the coordinates to find respective elevations.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lo3OV.png)

Kind regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be able to use something like:

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Header")
    ieobject.document.getElementById("locationSearchTextBox").Value = _
           .Range("B2").Value & "," & .Range("C2").Value
End with
```

Comment: need two small follow up resolution as well if you may.With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Header")
    ieobject.document.getElementById("locationSearchTextBox").Value = _
    .Range("B2").Value & "," & .Range("C2").Value

    ieobject.document.getElementById("fmtbutton").Click
    ieobject.document.getElementById("0EGu2eqKt6").Click

End With

Comment: What is the problem though?  Please update your question if you have code to add - it will be much easier to read there.  Don't forget after you submit a form you need to wait for the next page to finish loading before you try to access it...

Comment: need two small follow up resolution as well if you may. I searched on the webpage and could identify the getElementByID tag as follows for the search box. However, the said tag does not do any Click function. After wards, I manually pressed enter and again inspected element to identify the "0EGu2eqKt6" tag as elevation result. I would be grateful if you can help me in automate both the steps as I am getting debugging problems which are not helpful. Thank you